# Finding the CRC / Checksum in a control unit message

Tags: checksum, crc

I have a list of messages from a control unit that i'm trying to replicate.
I have the body of the message correct, however, i can't seem to work out what CRC or checksum is being utilised.

```
00 FE 0F 32 A8 80 84 90
00 FE 0F 32 A8 80 84 54
00 FE FF 31 A8 80 84 38
00 FE 0F 32 A8 80 84 DC
00 FE 0F 32 A8 80 84 90
00 FE 0F 32 A8 80 84 54
00 FE 0F 32 A8 80 84 18
00 FE 0F 32 A8 80 84 DC
00 FE 0F 32 A8 80 84 90
00 FE 1F 32 A8 80 84 44
00 FE 0F 32 A8 80 84 18
00 FE 0F 32 A8 80 84 DC
00 FE AF 31 A8 80 84 4C
00 FE BF 31 A8 80 84 F0
00 FE CF 31 A8 80 84 A4
```

I know the checksum is the last 4 bits in the last byte of the message. the other 4 bits in the last byte are a counter, that counts from 0 to 3 and then wraps back around.

I know the whole message is little endian as well.

I have run this in reveng (probably done it wrong) and it does not return any results.

I was hoping someone smarter than me would be able to assist with identifying this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: its not CRC, but rather: 16 - (Sum of Byte 0 to 7 % 16)